# Like Button of Facebook Page on website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I know that the procedure is simple, but for some reason I'm unable to add a Like Button for a facebook page on my website.

Here are the steps I followed:

```
 1. Make a Facebook page: myFacebookPage (`https://www.facebook.com/myFacebookPage`)
 2. Go to `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button`
 3. Add the page URL: `https://www.facebook.com/myFacebookPage` (It displays the like button there)
 4. Click "Get Code".
 5. Paste the code on my website page.
```

This code after the `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This code at the place I want my like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myFacebookPage" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

On opening the website, it displays the Like Button but doesn't allow me to like it. It displays that "Signup for Facebook" though, I'm already logged into Facebook on another tab.

Comment: The code to embed the JS SDK should include your app id – did you chose your app from the dropdown list on the page where you got the code from?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IFRAME instead of HTML5 to see if it works.

Comment: No success. It's still the same.

Comment: Can you provide a link or are you trying this offline?